# Why includes function doesn't use binary search

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why `Array.prototype.includes` doesn't use the binary search algorithm?

```
function BinarySearch(names,requiredName)
{
   return names.includes(requiredName)?true:false;
}
```

Comment: Why should the `includes()` method use binary search?

Comment: Also, no need for the ternary operator, as it already returns true or false

Comment: Binary search is well-suited for sorted arrays. `includes` doesn't consider this fact that the array is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary Search is an algorithm for searching a sorted array.

[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) should be able to work on any array or array-like object, not just an array that is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Because the spec says to search in *ascending* order instead:

[22.1.3.11 Array.prototype.includes](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes)

> NOTE 1
>
> **includes** compares searchElement to the elements of the array, in ascending order, using the SameValueZero algorithm, and if found at any position, returns **true**; otherwise, **false** is returned.

The interpreter has no way of knowing whether the array you call it on is sorted or not, nor of what sort of elements are in it. (imagine if the array was made of `HTMLElement`s, for example)